# merge 2 columns in pandas dataframe filling the NaNs with the previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
         State                           RegionName
0      Alabama                              Alabama
1          NaN                               Auburn
2          NaN                             Florence
3          NaN                         Jacksonville
4          NaN                           Livingston
5          NaN                           Montevallo
6          NaN                                 Troy
7          NaN                           Tuscaloosa
8          NaN                             Tuskegee
9       Alaska                               Alaska
10         NaN                            Fairbanks
11     Arizona                              Arizona
12         NaN                            Flagstaff
13         NaN                                Tempe
14         NaN                               Tucson
```

How can I return

```
DataFrame([["Alabama", "Auburn"], 
           ["Alabama", "Florence"], .
            .., 
           ["Alaska", "Fairbanks"],  
           ["Arizona", "Flagstaff"],  
           ...], columns=["State", "RegionName"])
```

so all values are mergend nicely?

I had tried: `df['State'] = df['State'].apply(lambda x: df['RegionName'])` but it lacks the logic of assigning new State for a RegionName when the new one starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['State'] = df['State'].ffill()
print (df)
      State    RegionName
0   Alabama       Alabama
1   Alabama        Auburn
2   Alabama      Florence
3   Alabama  Jacksonville
4   Alabama    Livingston
5   Alabama    Montevallo
6   Alabama          Troy
7   Alabama    Tuscaloosa
8   Alabama      Tuskegee
9    Alaska        Alaska
10   Alaska     Fairbanks
11  Arizona       Arizona
12  Arizona     Flagstaff
13  Arizona         Tempe
14  Arizona        Tucson
```

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me this is the first question which has `.ffill()` as an answer.

Comment: @DSM - I think it is super ;)

Comment: I guess what I was hinting at is that a question which has such a simple answer has probably been asked before, and instead of answering it again we should find the dupe.  When I get a second I can find a good target myself if no one else has yet.

Comment: @DSM - I agree, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @jezrael how can I delete the duplicate rows, e.g `Alabama       Alabama`, `Alaska        Alaska`?   I guess something similar to `df[['State'] != ['RegionName']]` has to be applied

Comment: `lst = list()` `for i in df.iterrows():` `if i[1][0] != i[1][1]:` `lst.append(i[1])` `newdf = pd.DataFrame(lst)`

Comment: Sorry, I dont get comment.

Comment: Give me a some time.

Comment: You are really close `df1 = df[df['State'] != df['RegionName']]`

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this solution is the index of df1 has some gaps in it for items have been removed: `print(df.index)` returns `Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,  10,  12,` As you can see 0 and 9 are gone (0 stood for Alabama, 9 was Alaska). I have tried to reset the index of df1 but there was no luck

Comment: Then use parameter `drop=True` -  `df1 = df[df['State'] != df['RegionName']].reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try fillna.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["Alabama", "Auburn"],
               [np.nan, "Florence"],
               [np.nan, "Fairbanks"],
               ["Arizona", "Flagstaff"]], columns=["State", "RegionName"])
df
Out[94]: 
     State RegionName
0  Alabama     Auburn
1      NaN   Florence
2      NaN  Fairbanks
3  Arizona  Flagstaff


df.fillna(method='ffill')
Out[95]: 
     State RegionName
0  Alabama     Auburn
1  Alabama   Florence
2  Alabama  Fairbanks
```